# Complexity of T(n)=T(cn)+T((1−c)n)

Tags: complexity-theory

i'm trying to calculate the complexity of `T(n)=T(cn)+T((1−c)n)+1`

my though was to change `T(n)+1 to S(n)`
and then i get

```
S(n)-1=S(cn)-1+S((1−c)n)-1+1 =====> S(n)=S(cn)+S((1−c)n)
```

but now i'm stuck with calculation.

Comment: What does this has to do with java?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to solve this with recurrence tree
                                                              Time comp

```
                       T(n)                              1                     
                       /  \                              
                      /    \
                 T(cn)      T((1-c)n)                    1
                /  \             /     \
               /    \           /       \
          T(ccn) T(c(1-c)n) T(c(1-c)n)   T((1-c)(1-c)n)  1
                                           |
                                           |
                                           |
                                         T(n(1-c)^k)
```

This will go on until we reach `n(1-c)^k=1`
solving this for **k**, gives **k=log<sub>1-c</sub>(1/n)**
So time complexity of each step is **O(1)**, Therefore
Total time complexity **TC=O(log<sub>1-c</sub>(1/n))**

Comment: number of iterations is  k=log1-c(1/n).  but wouldnt it change if c>0.5 and then the left side of the tree is longer than the right?   second question: do i have to power 2 by  k iterations in order to find the number of (max) inside "nodes"?

Comment: yes for c>0.5, left part will be longer, and answer will be log(1/n) base c.

Comment: @DinoCell  i didnt get ur second question?